# flask-ngrok app on google colab gave error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, flask, jupyter, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I'm making web demo for object detection using [this example](https://medium.com/csmadeeasy/send-and-receive-images-in-flask-in-memory-solution-21e0319dcc1).

It works on Win10 if I start with bash, but I'm using Detectron2 that works only on Linux/Mac. In this regard, I transferred `.py` script on Google Colab, but endpoint `/maskImage` didn't work.

Two days ago it worked somehow by magic, I didn't actually understand why, but now it crushed again. [Here](https://github.com/lilnyan/detection-demo) goes link with github repo with files and `.ipynb`.

I would appreciate suggestions on what this could be related to or how to fix it.

[error image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKJYa.jpg)

[error image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTPNl.jpg)